# Show element after pageload with ng-show and $window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a mainController which looks like below. I want to display a div after the completed pageload with ng-show. My `$scope.windowLoaded` is true after pageload, but the div with ng-show doesn't appear.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('mainController', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.windowLoaded = false;
    console.log('loading completed: ' + $scope.windowLoaded);
    $window.onload = function() {
      $scope.windowLoaded = true;
      console.log('loading completed: ' + $scope.windowLoaded);
    };

  });
```

html:

```
<div ng-show="windowLoaded == true">
    Show this div after pageload succeeded.
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)?

Comment: In my case ng-cloak is not what I need beacuse this doesn't react like jquery's `$(window).load()`

Comment: Fair enough. View my answer below then, should solve this and help with future similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be `ng-show="windowLoaded == 'true'"`. You are checking if `windowLoaded` equals a *string* of `true` instead of a boolean.

Replace it with:

```
<div ng-show="windowLoaded == true">
    Show this div after pageload succeeded.
</div>
```

**[Working Example](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/xVBgdm)**

---

If the problem persists after this, try wrapping your scope statement within a `$timeout` to make sure it is applied:

```
$window.onload = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.windowLoaded = true;
    });
};
```

Remember to pass `$timeout` into your controller though.

Comment: The div is definitely displayed for me? Checkout [this screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/9j6iqbktd/)

Comment: Also, you forgot to pass `$timeout` into your controller. Fixed it here - http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/grEgoM

Comment: No problem @herrh :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
 $scope.windowLoaded = true;
});
```

Comment: Be careful with `$apply()` as it can generate an error of `$digest already in progress` if used while a template digest is still in progress. Using `$timeout` avoids this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also using viewContentLoaded event

```
    myapp.controller('MyController', ['$scope'
      function($scope) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {$scope.windowLoaded = true;}); 
   }]);
```